# Algorithm to scale a raw 24 bit pixelmap to greater than 50% in C

Tags: c, image, image-processing, bitmap, x11

Reducing a raw pixelmap to a value of 50% is easy.  I simply slide a 2x2 square across the map and average the RGB components of the 4 pixels as follows:

```
 img = XGetImage(d_remote,RootWindow(d_remote,0),0,0,attr.width,attr.height,XAllPlanes(),ZPixmap);

   int i;
   int j;
   for(i=0;i<attr.height;i=i+2){
        for(j=0;j<attr.width;j=j+2) {
                unsigned long p1 = XGetPixel(img, j, i);
                unsigned long p1R = p1 & 0x00ff0000;
                unsigned long p1G = p1 & 0x0000ff00;
                unsigned long p1B = p1 & 0x000000ff;

                unsigned long p2 = XGetPixel(img, j+1, i);
                unsigned long p2R = p2 & 0x00ff0000;
                unsigned long p2G = p2 & 0x0000ff00;
                unsigned long p2B = p2 & 0x000000ff;

                unsigned long p3 = XGetPixel(img, j, i+1);
                unsigned long p3R = p3 & 0x00ff0000;
                unsigned long p3G = p3 & 0x0000ff00;
                unsigned long p3B = p3 & 0x000000ff;

                unsigned long p4 = XGetPixel(img, j+1, i+1);
                unsigned long p4R = p4 & 0x00ff0000;
                unsigned long p4G = p4 & 0x0000ff00;
                unsigned long p4B = p4 & 0x000000ff;

                unsigned long averageR = (p1R+p2R+p3R+p4R)/4 & 0x00ff0000;
                unsigned long averageG = (p1G+p2G+p3G+p4G)/4 & 0x0000ff00;
                unsigned long averageB = (p1B+p2B+p3B+p4B)/4 & 0x000000ff;

                int average = averageR | averageG | averageB;

                XPutPixel(newImg, j/2, i/2, average);

        }
   }
```

This would make a pixelmap that is 500x500 turn into one that is 250x250.  This is a 50% reduction.  What if I wanted to scale it by 20%.  For example I would like my 500x500 image to turn into 400x400?  The smallest square I can slide is a 2x2.  I don't see how I can get a reduction that is not a perfect power of 2.

## Solution:

How's this for effort??  I modified a script I found that does bi-linear interpolation to work on XImages.  It should work for any generic pixelmap.  I do find the code ugly though since I see images as 2d arrays.  I don't see why all the image code is mapped to a 1d array.  It's harder to visualize.  This works for any resize.

```
void resize(XImage* input, XImage* output, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
{
    int a, b, c, d, x, y, index;
    float x_ratio = ((float)(sourceWidth - 1)) / targetWidth;
    float y_ratio = ((float)(sourceHeight - 1)) / targetHeight;
    float x_diff, y_diff, blue, red, green ;
    int offset = 0 ;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    int* inputData = (int*)input->data;
    int* outputData = (int*)output->data;
    for (i = 0; i < targetHeight; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < targetWidth; j++)
        {
            x = (int)(x_ratio * j) ;
            y = (int)(y_ratio * i) ;
            x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x ;
            y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y ;
            index = (y * sourceWidth + x) ;
            a = inputData[index] ;
            b = inputData[index + 1] ;
            c = inputData[index + sourceWidth] ;
            d = inputData[index + sourceWidth + 1] ;

            // blue element
            blue = (a&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + (b&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                   (c&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + (d&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // green element
            green = ((a>>8)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                    ((c>>8)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // red element
            red = ((a>>16)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                  ((c>>16)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);


            outputData[offset++] = (int)red << 16 | (int)green << 8 | (int)blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Slide" a 1.25 x 1.25 square across. If the 1.25x1.25 square overlaps several squares, weigh the averages accordingly to pretend you are only looking at a 1.25x1.25 area.

Comment: Yes but my i and j can only increase by a whole number and I can only access a whole numbered pixel.

Comment: That's what the weighted averages are for - it let's you "access" a fraction of a pixel.

Comment: -1 This is the exact code from your previous question.

Comment: instead of incrementing by 2 (which is the result of the division : 100/50) relatively you can increment by 5 in case of 20% (100/20 = 5), if you want to make the pixels in between affected, they will be affected by a percentage of the distance between them and the blended pixels .. example: pixel 4 blended with pixel 5 in 50:50, pixel 0 is far from pixel 4 by 4 so pixel 0 and 3 will be blended with the adjacent by 25(adjacent):75(0 and 3) as in 100/4 = 25, for p1 and p2 they will remain as they are .. just a suggestion, didn't test the result yet.

Comment: @luser droog Yes it is because overnight I was thinking about how to extend it to scale greater than 50%.  I appreciate the answer on the other question as it helped me to scale to 50% which I had a problem doing.  This is a different question about the same code.

Comment: I understand all that. But you should make an attempt to solve it yourself first. I can (and will) remove the downvote if you edit the question to show some effort.

Comment: s/if/if (and only if)/

Comment: @luserdroog .  There I made some effort.  Can I have my upvote back ;).  I ended up abandoning the system and using VNC to achieve my goals since this ended up consuming 100% system memory!

Comment: @johndoe Done. [nit: if this is the solution, it should go in an answer.]

Comment: @johndoe Do my comments make sense to you? I'm really not trying to be a jerk, but to help make the site better. It's a "feature" of the site that you can't change a vote unless an edit is made.

Comment: @luserdroog gotcha.  To be fair I should at least ATTEMPT a solution.  No hard feelings.

Comment: Awesome. BTW, both these questions are 'favorites' of mine. I expect to steal from them in the future! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode for downscaling. WS,HS is the target image size WB,HB is the source size. WS is less than WB and HS is less than HB.

```
double row[WB];
double Xratio= WB/WS;
double Yratio= HB/HS;

double curYratio= Yratio;
double remainY= Yratio - floor(Yratio);
double remainX= Xratio - floor(Xratio);
double curXratio;

double rfac, cfac;

int icol,irow, orow, ocol;

zero-out row

orow= 0;

for(irow=0..HB-1)
{
  // we find out how much of this row we will add to the current sum
  if (curYratio>=1.0) rfac= 1.0; else rfac= curYratio;

  // we add it
  for(icol=0..WB)     row[icol] += rfac * input[irow][icol];

  // we reduce the total weight 
  curYratio -= rfac;

  // if the total weight is now zero, we have a complete row,
  // otherwise we still need some of the next row
  if (curYratio!=0.0) continue;

  // we have a complete row, compute the weighted average
  for(icol=0..WB-1)   row[icol]/= Yratio; 

  // now we can scale the row in horizontal

  curXratio= Xratio;
  ocol= 0; 
  double pixel= 0.0;
  for(icol=0..WB-1)
  {
    if (curXratio>=1.0)  cfac= 1.0; else cfac= curXratio;
    pixel+= row[icol]*cfac;
    curXratio -= cfac;
    if (curXratio!=0) continue;

    // now we have a complete pixel
    out[orow][ocol]= pixel / Xratio;
    pixel= remainX * row[icol];
    curXratio= Xratio - remainX;   
    ocol++;
  }
  orow++;

  // let's put the remainder of the last input row into 'row'

  for(icol=0..WB-1)     row[i]= remainY*input[irow][icol];
  curYratio= Yratio - remainY;
}
```

This took longer than I thought it would, but there it is. Anyway, it's not very wise to run this directly on an input bitmap. You should convert each pixel value to it's sRGB value before doing any arithmetic. The pixel values in a common bitmap are just names for the real values which should be used in computations. Look up sRGB on wikipedia, it has good information.

If you do it without converting to sRGB and back, you will have a darker image when you scale down.